# Set default Locale to DatePicker and TimePicker

Tags: android, localization, arabic, android-datepicker, android-timepicker

I'm using a `DatePicker` and a `TimePicker` in a custom `Dialog`. The functionality works fine, but I have a problem when I change the default `Locale` of the app to match the Arabic language.

The problem is that the `DatePicker` and `TimePicker` are not localized on all Android versions. It works on Android versions 4.2.2 and higher. But It doesn't work on Android versions 4.1.2 And lower.

I want to either change localization of `DatePicker` and `TimePicker` to English all the time, Or to change it to Arabic when the `Locale` matches the Arabic language.

This is the dialog in Android versions 4.2.2 and higher (the correct one that matches the localization)

[image: Android version 4.2.2 and higher]

And this is the dialog in Android versions 4.1.2 and lower

[image: Android versions 4.1.2 and lower]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create your custom DatePicker or TimePicker
.
See this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/9220899/3864698. It can help you to solve your problem.

Or you can use Reflection to edit the NumberPicker values, follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257014/set-language-to-french-in-android-datepickerdialog/25486882#25486882) for the complete solution.

Comment: Is there a way to change the Months strings in the DatePicker instead of creating a custom one?

Comment: I see that you found some solution. In other case unfortunately i don't see any possibility to do it. Here link to customize your DatePicker http://stackoverflow.com/a/25486882/3864698

Comment: @AbdallahAlaraby any solution for this without custom?

Answer (score 0):

if you pass the current locale to `SimpleDateFormat` Object you will get your locale picker for example you can consider following snippet code

```
@NotNull
public static Calendar getPickedTime(@NotNull String selectedTimeStr) {
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa",Locale.US);
    try {
        calendar.setTime(simpleDateFormat.parse(selectedTimeStr));
        Log.d(TAG, "getPickedTime: "+calendar.getTime());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return calendar;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Please change the locale in your fragment/activity, before showing DatePicker/TimePicker.

Locale locale = Locale.US; //Your specific locale.
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

```
    Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    configuration.setLocale(locale);
    configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);

    context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
```