# How to change locale to use Latin Serbian (instead of Cyrillic Serbian)

Tags: android, locale, country-codes

The Serbian language has Latin and Cyrillic alphabets. In Android's Date and Time Picker widgets, the displayed alphabet for Serbian locales seems to be Cyrillic, as seen here.

[image]

I wanted to change the locale so that the android widgets are using the Latin Serbian alphabet.

The current language/country code (yielding Cyrillic) are `sr` and `RS` respectively. Therefore, my setLocale function is called as

```
setLocale("sr", "RS");
```

This is the part im not sure about - according to [localeplanet.com](http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/sr-Latn-RS/), the local code for latin serbian is `sr_Latn_RS`. However, I tried both

```
setLocale("sr_Latn", "RS");
//and
setLocale("sr_Latn_RS", "RS");
```

neither of which work (no change occurs, default to english). According to the Android documentation, it looks like setLocale expects two letter codes.

> The language codes are two-letter lowercase ISO language codes (such
>   as "en") as defined by ISO 639-1. The country codes are two-letter
>   uppercase ISO country codes (such as "US") as defined by ISO 3166-1.
>   The variant codes are unspecified.

So how do I specify a Latin serbian locale code? Or does it not exist?

Answer (score 4):

The previous answer works well if you only support Lollipop or above. However, if you're coding in Serbian a lot of your user base probably won't have it. Here's a solution that works for old and new versions.

```
private static Locale serbianLatinLocale(){

    Locale locale = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        for (Locale checkLocale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
            if (checkLocale.getISO3Language().equals("srp") && checkLocale.getCountry().equals("LATN") && checkLocale.getVariant().equals("")) {
                locale = checkLocale;
            }
        }
    } else {
        locale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("sr").setRegion("RS").setScript("Latn").build();
    }

    return locale;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For getting latin locale I first used code below.

```
new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("sr").setRegion("RS").setScript("Latn").build();
```

But this solution didn't work on my Android 5.1.1 device (it was still in cyrillic). So I removed setting of region like this:

```
new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("sr").setScript("Latn").build();
```

And you have to put your string for serbian resources in b+sr+Latn folder.

Answer (score 0):

Please search for your query before posting a question. It may be answered in some other related form.

```
    Locale newLocale = new Locale("sr","RS");
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.setLocale(newLocale);
    // using this to reference my Activity
    this.getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, this.getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

i found these two answers suitable to your query 
[android custom date-picker SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219367/android-datepicker-typeface/9220899#9220899) and [locale from english to french](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257014/set-language-to-french-in-android-datepickerdialog/25486882#25486882).

**EDIT**

```
    Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
    for(Locale locale : locales){
        if(locale.getCountry().equalsIgnoreCase("RS")
                && locale.getScript().equalsIgnoreCase("Latn"))
        {
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.setLocale(locale);
            // using this to reference my Activity
            this.getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, this.getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            break;
        }
    }
```

I know there will be an efficient way to do it, however you may get the direction that you need to get the list of available locales and get the locale you desire. Hope it helps

**EDIT-2 (Final)**

you can construct the locale using:

```
Locale locale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("sr").setRegion("RS").setScript("Latn").build();
setLocale(locale);
```

Comment: haha, ok on it, the title was a little misleading but i am doing my research to help you find the answer

Comment: done Eric, you can use the last edit. Sorry for so many edits

Comment: Last peace of code required API >= 21  but I need it for API 19... Any workaround?

Comment: @cizola I've just added a solution. You may want to cache it if you're pulling the locale a lot, but you're just setting it once or something it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please use below one ?

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Resources res = this.getResources();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        boolean isLatinAlphabet = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        if(conf.locale.getLanguage().equals("sr") && isLatinAlphabet) {
            conf.locale = new Locale("sr", "YourContryCode");
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, res.getDisplayMetrics());
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** Replace your `YourContryCode` in `conf.locale = new Locale("sr", "YourContryCode");` line.

**Manifest.xml**:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/application_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

   ...

</application>
```

Hope this will help you.