# Android Serbian latin and Montenegro values folder for strings.xml

Tags: android, localization, locale

I am trying to translate strings.xml for Serbian latin (srpski) and Montenegro (both Cyrillic and Latin) . I have included Serbian Cyrillic (српски) in values folder as values-sr. And it works fine. But for Serbian latin & Montenegro, I am unable to decide what should be the name of the values folder.I went through many posts in SO like

[How to change locale to use Latin Serbian (instead of Cyrillic Serbian)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35877037/how-to-change-locale-to-use-latin-serbian-instead-of-cyrillic-serbian)

[What should be the values folder name for Serbian (Latin,Serbia) (sr-rs-latn) language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32523596/what-should-be-the-values-folder-name-for-serbian-latin-serbia-sr-rs-latn-la)

but they didnt help much.

I understand from https://github.com/championswimmer/android-locales that values folder should be :

Serbian (Cyrillic)  sr      -->            **values-sr-r_#Cyrl**

Serbian (Cyrillic,Montenegro)   sr  ME -->  **values-sr-rME_#Cyrl**

Serbian (Cyrillic,Serbia)   sr  RS -->      **values-sr-rRS_#Cyrl**

Serbian (Latin) sr -->      **values-sr-r_#Latn**

Serbian (Latin,Montenegro)  sr  ME -->  **values-sr-rME_#Latn**

Serbian (Latin,Serbia)  sr  RS -->  **values-sr-rRS_#Latn**

But if I try to create a folder like values-sr-rRS_#Latn in Android studio, it throws error "Invalid directory". Then I started some analysis.

1. In Nexus 9 Marshmallow, list of available locales using Locale.getAvailableLocales() lists all the serbian languages. So they are supported.

   sr
   sr__#Cyrl
   sr_BA_#Cyrl
   sr_ME_#Cyrl
   sr_RS_#Cyrl
   sr_XK_#Cyrl
   sr__#Latn
   sr_BA_#Latn
   sr_ME_#Latn
   sr_RS_#Latn
   sr_XK_#Latn
2. In Settings screen of Nexus 9, I can see option to only change to Serbian Cyrillic(српски) whereas in a Lenovo Yoga tab, I see option to change to only Serbian latin(srpski). When I debugged in both the devices, I found that both have **sr**  as the language code and **RS** as the region code and the script code was blank. So how to include both values folder in app and how its mapped?
3. Should I create values folder like values-sr-ZZ or something for the languages I need and in code check for the script code?
4. But if that's the case, in resources folder of Google Play Games and Settings app I found that they have only one values-sr folder. So how do they handle values-sr-r_#Latn and values-sr-rME_#Latn and values-sr-rME_#Cyrl.

Can anyone please guide me ?

Comment: Jesi uspio rijesiti ovo?

Answer (score 6):

I have just successfully used:

> values-b+sr+Latn

Also see [Android build error for values-b+sr+Latn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39947606/android-build-error-for-values-bsrlatn) if you can't get past *Invalid directory* issue