# Android Studio showing invalid resource directory name

Tags: android, android-studio

> invalid resource directory name: C:\Users\kichu\AndroidStudioProjects\HWorld\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug/values-b+sr+Latn

I am a beginner to Android Studio, so I downloaded the .exe file and just installed it.. no other changes..some update came in though..

When I was trying to create a "hello world".. this thing pops up
I saw when I googled Android doesn't support '+' file directory name is it so?
If yes, then why is it creating this by itself..
would like some help regarding this.

Comment: I tried using aaptOptions {
    ignoreAssetsPatternaaptOptions {
        ignoreAssetsPattern "!values-b+sr+Latn"
    } "!values-b+sr+Latn"
}      but it shows could not find aaptoptions() for arguments

Answer (score 0):

Generally your resource file names shouldn't have "+" in them, and it's strange that you'd see that in an automatically generated file.

I took a look at one of my projects, and sure enough I also have that file. It's also **the only** file in that directory with a "+" in the name. My guess is that some of your language and localization settings on your computer are set to Serbian, and on installation or during compilation it checked your locale and used "values-b+sr+Latn.xml".

Someone already posted a similar but more detailed question here: [Android build error for values-b+sr+Latn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39947606/android-build-error-for-values-bsrlatn), so you can take a look at the proposed solution and see if it works.

If not, try changing your language and locations settings for your computer and building again, then re-installing Android Studio with the new settings if that doesn't work.

Comment: Could u tell me where i can change the settings ,i searched my control panel through and couldnt find any serbian settings i am using windows 8 , where should i change kindly advice

Comment: I don't use Windows 8, but it should be wherever you can change the language of your keyboard and in general system settings for your menus and stuff. Do you use a Serbian keyboard and/or menus?